# How to delete object property and assign in new variable?

Tags: angular

I've issue when take object and use .map() to delete a property from it and assign it to a new variable, actually it's working but also is removing the property from the obj `products` which I don't want.

```
filteredProduct;

calcShipPrice() {
  this.checkoutForm.patchValue({
  product: this.products,
  delivery: this.selectedDelivery,
  total: this.totalPrice
});
// remove two properties from the obj and submit just name and price of product
this.filteredProduct = this.products.map(res => delete res.image && delete res.description);
console.log(this.products);
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways by using destructuring, is you have lots of properties 
this.filteredProduct = this.products.map(({image, description,... rest}) => rest);

Or if is just a few properties 
this.filteredProduct = this.products.map(({name, price}) => ({name, price}));

Comment: Both of your ways are working, when I log it I recieve what I want, but when put the variable (this.filteredProduct) in patchValue product: this.filteredProduct, in the submitted form for 'product' is showing me empty array, this.filteredProduct the type is [ ];
Any suggestions? 
Thx anyway!

Comment: Humm looks like an ordering problem are you sure your map statement is executed before you use patchValue in the form, where are you putting each logic the one that maps and the one that calls the patchValue

Comment: Sorry mate my bad, I was did it after patchValue that's why wasn't submitting, now I move before patchValue and is work as should be, thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
this.filteredProduct = this.products.map((product) => { return {
name: res.name, price: res.price
}});
console.log('this.filteredProduct', this.filteredProduct);
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry my bad, I missed the syntax here. Updated the answer with a mock example please give it a try, see if it helps.

Comment: Well it's working, I just replace "res" with "product" - name: product.name, price: product.price, thank you so much!